# auto update date in R syntax

Tags: r, date

First, this is my first question on here, sorry if i don't ask this question as clearly as possible.

I am trying to automatically update the dates in the syntax below:

```
Xyz_tweets <- search_tweets("Xyz, since:2020-6-20 until:2020-6-21" ,n = 15000, lang = "en" )
```

I created two objects:

```
sincetdate <- Sys.Date() - 1
untildate <- Sys.Date()
```

and then tried to save in a string:

```
searchquery <- paste( "Xyz_tweets <- search_tweets(Xyz, since:",sincedate,  "until:", untildate, "n = 15000, lang = "en" )")
```

and then use

```
eval(parse(text=searchquery))
```

to have the string evaluated as an expression.
but it is not working.  I  get an error message:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "searchquery <- paste( "SCUBA_tweets <- search_tweets(SCUBA, since:",sincedate,  "until:", untildate, "n = 15000, lang = "en"

Works fine when i just use the dates like:

```
searchquery3 = 'SCUBA_tweets <- search_tweets("SCUBA, since:2020-6-20 until:2020-6-21" ,n = 15000, lang = "en" )'
```

and then

```
eval(parse(searchquery3))
```

how do i get

```
searchquery <- paste( "Xyz_tweets <- search_tweets(Xyz, since:",sincedate,  "until:", untildate, "n = 15000, lang = "en" )")
eval(parse(text=searchquery))
```

to work?

Comment: to use quotes inside double quotes, you either need to 1) escape them `\"en\"` or 2) use single quotes `'en'` or vice versa. Also, why are you writing out the entire expression and parsing rather than just the text string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
searchquery <- paste0("Xyz, since:", sincedate, " until:", untildate)
Xyz_tweets <- search_tweets(searchquery, n = 15000, lang = "en")
```

You can just build the search query and then use it inside `search_tweets()`. It's cleaner and much safer than using `eval()`.

Comment: THANK YOU for your help